# How do I add an array of images to separate image views?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, uiimageview

I have an array of image views:

```
var imageViewArray = [UIImageView(image: UIImage())]
```

I use a loop to fill it with images from url's.  I then want to put these images into separate image views.  Whenever I try, it just keeps replacing them in the same image view when I do this:

```
for image in imageViewArray {
     self.view.addSubview(image)
}
```

So how do I make different image views for all these images?  I don't want to use a collection view or table view though.  There won't be any scrolling and I need some of them to overlap which I don't know if you can do that with collection view. Also the number of images can vary.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's replacing each image in the same imageView? Depending on how your layout is, I'd think you are overlaying one imageView with another - if you have 5 images/imageViews, you are ending up with 5 overlapping imageViews.

Comment: I can just tell using the print command, ran some tests.  There is only one image view and there should be more.

Comment: Well, the code you have shown looks good to me. Maybe you need to post more code. The only other thought I have is to put a breakpoint (maybe in your loop) to check if (1) you actually have more than one imageView in the array, and (2) see what is happening when iterating through it.

Comment: You know what, it's working now.  I think what happened was simulator problems because I'm using firebase and old firebase data somehow gets stuck in the simulator and you have to delete the app after deleting data from firebase.  My bad, but it was really helpful for you to confirm the code, because then I started looking for problems elsewhere.  Thanks!